# Unresolved External Symbol with external get function

Tags: c

I keep getting a linker error with the following setup.

I have file1.c which contains the following code

```
#if defined( _TEST_ENABLED )

int get_value()
{
.
.
.    
}
#endif  /*_TEST_ENABLED   */
```

I have file2.c which includes file2.h, which defines _TEST_ENABLED. file2.c makes a call to get_value(), however the linker isn't having any part of that.

I've exhausted a lot of different options with zero success. Now i'm asking for help :)

Comment: Please share the command line you use to compile this program.

Comment: Are you sure the linker is using both files?

Comment: Ok, so you've ensured that _TEST_ENABLED is defined when compiling file2.c. But what about when compiling file1.c?

Comment: Are you also including file2.h in file2.c?  And unless the prototype of `int get_value(void) is included where it is visible to file2.c, it will not be defined there.  Try incuding a prototype in the header file that is visible to both .c files,

Comment: Note: leading underscores are reserved for the language and / or the implementation. `_TEST_ENABLED` -->> `TEST_ENABLED`

Answer (score 1):

If file1.c does not include file2.h or any file which defines `_TEST_ENABLED`, `_TEST_ENABLED` will not be defined when the preprocessor runs on file1.c, so `int get_value() { ... }` will not get compiled.

Comment: file1.c also includes file2.h

Answer (score 0):

In order to call a function in another file:

1) The files must be compiled or at least linked together. The easiest way to do this is `gcc file1.c file2.c`, however you can also compile both files to `*.o` files and then link together.

2) The calling file must have, usually through an included header, a prototype of the function. This prototype must appear before the function is used. So, if `file2.h` defines `_TEST_ENABLED`, then you must (in `file2.c`) include `file2.h`, and then either `file2.c` or `file2.h` must include `file1.h`, which must contain a function prototype (`int get_value;`)

For example:

file1.c

```
#include <file1.h>
#include <file2.h>

int main() {
  get_value();
}
```

file1.h

```
#ifndef _FILE2_H
#define _FILE2_H

#define _TEST_ENABLED

#endif
```

file2.c

```
#include <file2.h>
#include <file1.h>

#ifdef _TEST_ENABLED
int get_value() {
  return 42;
}
#endif
```

file2.h

```
#ifndef _FILE2_H
#define _FILE2_H

int get_value();

#endif
```

Note that for the purposes of the preprocessor, `file1.c` and `file2.c` are processed completely separately. When processing `file2.c`, it MUST find `#define _TEST_ENABLED` somewhere, which is why `file2.c` must include `file1.h`. Since this is getting a little circular, you should add "`#include`-guards to each header file, as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

There are some ambiguities in your question, but given the following three files, I can compile and build in ANSI C, but I have to include the .h in both .cs:

***file1.c***

```
#include "file2.h"

int main(void)
{
    someFunc();
    get_value();
    return 0;   
}

#ifdef _TEST_ENABLED
int get_value(void)
{
    return 0;   
}
#endif
```

***file2.c***

```
#include "file2.h"

int someFunc(void);

int someFunc(void)
{
    get_value();
    return 0;
}
```

***file2.h***

```
#define _TEST_ENABLED

int get_value(void);
```